# How to upload a Debian package to a repository when you have only the .deb file?

Tags: repository, debian, reprepro

I have a local Debian repository I run for our organization using `reprepro`. This local repository hosts custom software we develop ourselves. There are Debian packages from other sources not included in the official Debian repos that I would like to add to our local repository.

Normally when I build a package I upload it to our local repository using `dput` which requires a `.changes` file. If I get a  Debian package from another source, I get only a `.deb` file and no `.changes` file.

How do I upload a `.deb` file to our local repository without the `.changes` file?

Comment: And how is this related to Ubuntu? Please edit your answer and add which version of Ubuntu this question is for.

Comment: @user68186 -- ubuntu uses debian packages (note: this refers to package type not distro name)

Comment: @ravery - Well Ubuntu uses Debian packaging, apt, and .deb, that does not mean you can install any .deb on Ubuntu, nor does it mean you can install a Debian package, .deb or not. Also repository names / structure an not the same for Debian (squeeze or wheezy) or Ubuntu (trusty and zenial and artful) So it makes a difference if this repository is for Debian or Ubuntu .

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/SetupWithReprepro#Adding_packages_to_the_repository

Comment: @Panther -- actually you can install any .deb package on ubuntu, if you can meet the dependencies. And the command is the same for Debian and Ubuntu `reprepro includedeb <osrelease> <debfile>`.

Comment: @ravery the point I am making is "if" , you can not install all .deb and you can cause breakage if you install a Debian package , even if the dependencies are met, due to differences in libs, even if the libs have the same name, they may be differences. And second the Debian osrelease != Ubuntu osrelease so be careful when installing Debian packages on Ubuntu or the other way around.

Comment: There are many distros that uses deb packages. However, only questions about currently supported versions of Ubuntu and  its official derivatives are on-topic here. If your question is about Debian, Mint, or any other Debian based distro, or about versions of Ubuntu that have reached the end of their life, then the question is off-topic. If your question is about generic Debian repositories, you may want to ask it in unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have never had to use a changes file for uploading to my reprepro repository. As far as I know, having a changes file is optional, [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/SetupWithReprepro) simply ignores it as an extra step.

Comment: ... and why are you using `dput` if you're not building your own packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reprepro, you don't need a changes file for uploading a deb file. There's the `includedeb` subcommand:

```
$ reprepro -b /var/www/repo includedeb xenial grep_3.1-2\~16.04.york0_amd64.deb
Exporting indices...
$ cd /var/www/repo; find pool
pool
pool/main
pool/main/g
pool/main/g/grep
pool/main/g/grep/grep_3.1-2~16.04.york0_amd64.deb
```

Change `-b /var/www/repo` to suit wherever your reprepro root directory is located.